# Firebug 2.0.4 hanging websites in Firefox 32.0 using Polymer

Tags: firefox, firebug, polymer

Since the update to Firebug 2.0.4 in Firefox 32.0 on 06-09-2014 I've been experiencing problems using Polymer. Whenever I reload a page using Polymer (also using the website [polymer-project.org](http://polymer-project.org)) with Firebug open on that site Firefox will hang telling that the problem is coming from:

Script: chrome://firebug/content/debugger/script/sourceTool.js:791

I downgraded to an earlier version of Firebug and the browser stops hanging on reloading.

This works for now but does anyone know a different way to resolve this or anything?

Comment: I guess with "newest Firebug" you mean Firebug 2.0.* and with "crashing websites" you mean they hang the browser (but don't crash it), right? So please update your question to include the versions of Firebug and Firefox and clarify what exactly you see.

Comment: Thanks, i added the additional information.

Comment: I'm not sure if it even requires Polymer, or at least I don't know what Polymer is, but I'm experiencing this issue on a local development site. Fairly occasional. Will try downgrading Firebug.

Comment: Are you using Web Components on your website by any chance?

Comment: This issue https://code.google.com/p/fbug/issues/detail?id=7560 looks similar to your problem. Marked as fixed in Firebug 2.0.3. But I still have the same problems with hanging in Firefox 33.0 + Firebug 2.0.4 when switching between my React app pages. Maybe the reason is not optimized script highlighting: https://code.google.com/p/fbug/issues/detail?id=7679&q=scipt%20panel&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Test%20Summary%20Reporter